# Shofar and Lulav on Shabbos - how can Rabbinical decree override Deorayso

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, rabbis, derabanan, dechiya-superseding

The gezaira of Raba is that when Purim Sukkos or Rosh hashana fall out on shabbos we do not blow shofar or shake lulav or read the meggila.

Why?  Because we are worried that he may not know what to do, and go to a Baki to find out what to do.

How can it be that just because of a worry that one may not know the halochos,

We are uprooting a biblical commandment it is no simple thing to just skip a mitzva deorraisa. So what is logic behind this gezaira that it is strong enogh to move a mitzva (every mitzva is needed in this world so how can we not do it because of a worry-cheshash)

Comment: See REM on Tosfot on SMAG, hilchot chofar, DH ein Toq'in

Comment: Megillah on Purim is not "d'oraysa"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chabad Chassidus explains that it is very unlikely the reason not to blow shofar in shabbos is in case you carry the shofar. It seems more the chachamim felt it was not appropriate for some reason to blow the shofar on shabbos and looked for a halachical pretext with the boundaries of their legislative powers to forbid this. (R' Schneur Zalman of Liadi, Liqutei Torah, Derushei Rosh Hashanah 56a ff)

Transcedental reasons are not halachically binding, i.e. you always need a peshat excuse for remez, derush or sod, especially when you are up against a mitzva de'oraysah.